# Java Server Page || Приоритет по файлам?

Tags: java, jsp

Когда запускаю JSP Web Application на Tomcat или JBoss Server, оно запускает index.jsp первым (index.jsp файл автоматом создается при созданий проекта), но если добавить в папку WEB-INF другие файлы .htmk, .jsp, то оно открывает эти файлы, а не начальный index.jsp.
Какой приоритет JSP отдает при открытий файлов? По алфавитному порядку, либо HTML -> CSS -> JSP или ?
Какую последовательность оно использует ?

Comment: В папке WEB-INF все что хранится недоступно для сервера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стандартный приоритет "страниц приветствия":

- index.html
- index.htm
- index.jsp

Кроме этого в `web.xml` [можно задать](https://www.javatpoint.com/welcome-file-list) собственный список страниц приветствия при помощи тэга welcome-file-list. Страницы из этого списка будут иметь наивысший приоритет.

Answer (score 0):

E Вас есть нижеследующее в `applicatin.properties` ?

```
# jsp cfg
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/ 
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

[подсмотрено  здесь](https://hellokoding.com/spring-boot-hello-world-example-with-freemarker/)